# Bind Picker selected value to a property Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, picker

How to associate a property with the selected item of a picker?

```
var kmList = new List<string>();
kmList.Add("1");
kmList.Add("2");
kmList.Add("3");
kmList.Add("4");
kmList.Add("5");
kmList.Add("6");
kmList.Add("7");

var picker = new Picker { Title = "Select a km", TitleColor = Color.Red };
picker.ItemsSource = kmList;
```

For example, if I choose the 7, then it is necessary that this value be available in the variable SelectedNumber:

```
    public class TodoItem
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SelectedNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

The resulting value from the picker needs to be saved to the database, but first, I need to set the `SelectedNumber` value with the picker selected item.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind your ViewModel selected item property to `SelectedItem` property of the Picker, like this:

```
public class Monkey
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}

public class MonkeysViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Monkey> Monkeys { get; set; }

    public Monkey SelectedMonkey { get; set; }
}

<Picker Title="Select a monkey"
    TitleColor="Red"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMonkey}" />
```

Also, you can read more about this in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource#responding-to-item-selection-1).

Comment: I read it several times, but I could not understand how to do this in c #.
class Monkey is understandable
class MonkeysViewModel - I do not understand why it need

what is responsible for binding the data from this ItemsSource, ItemDisplayBinding or SelectedItem,
How to bind data on with C#?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. On c # it looks like this

```
picker.SetBinding(Picker.SelectedItemProperty, "SelectedNumber");
```